# Добавить пункт "Неотвеченные" в меню сайта

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, навигация

На [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) левое меню выглядит так:

> [image: ruSO]

В свою очередь на сайте ["Русский язык"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) имеется дополнительный пункт "Неотвеченные":

> [image: Русский язык]

Данный пункт ведёт на страницу неотвеченных вопросов, т.е. вопросов, у которых нет принятых или ответов с положительным рейтингом.

Такая страница вполне себе [существует на ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/) и, я считаю, вполне можно было бы оставить ссылку на неё из этого меню, особенно учитывая, что места там для новых пунктов более чем достаточно.

Наличие прямой ссылки позволит быстрее, а стало быть чаще посещать страницы вопросов, требующих ответа, где, как ни странно, желающий сможет дать ответ и сократить (как минимум сделать первый шаг к этому) тем самым кол-во неотвеченных вопросов. А это, между прочим, [один из критериев оценки сайта](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered) и мы в этом списке очень далеко от лучших представителей.

Comment: @Nicolas, почему Meta сайт обошли стороной? Тут тоже хорошо бы добавить в меню.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это предложение более чем корректно, так как абсолютно все сайты сети Stack Exchange имеют пункт "Неотвеченные" в своих меню. Хотя меню большого Stack Overflow совершенно отличается от всей сети (тем не менее, не вижу препятствий добавить пункт "Неотвеченные" и туда), меню локализованных Stack Overflow ничем не отличаются от остальных сайтов сети кроме отсутствия уже упомянутого пункта "Неотвеченные".

Так как предложение затрагивает разные сайты и было бы хорошо исправить всё за раз, то создал предложение об этом на главной мете:
[Add "Unanswered" menu item for international Stack Overflow Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329271/346987). Пожалуйста, проголосуйте на главной мете, возможно, это предложение будет иметь результат.

Answer (score 3):

Сайты Stack Overflow живут несколько отдельно от остальной сети Stack Exchange, поэтому, во времена старой горизонтальной навигации, когда добавляли раздел вакансий на сайт, ссылка на вопросы без ответа пропала со всех Stack Overflow.

Наличие ссылки на вопросы без ответа в главной навигации контролируется настройкой сайта, которая ни к чему, например, стадии развития сайта, не привязана. Коллеги также не видят причин, почему мы не должны вернуть этот раздел в основное меню.

Задал вопрос на остальных международных сайтах. Если не появятся какие–то новые неизвестные сейчас преграды, активируем во всех сообществах, которые будут за.

Вопросы на других Метах:

1. [Португальская](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7944/125288).
2. [Испанская](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4339/99796).
3. [Японская](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3093/30081).

Comment: Если гугл.транслейт меня не обманывает, народ высказывается за. Будут ли приняты какие-то дальнейшие действия со стороны сотрудников SO? Или надо "немножко" подождать (6-8 недель)?

Comment: Ну как, уже можно включить?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica по-моему, надо снова на MSE это вопрос переподнимать. КМ, похоже, в отпуске, или занят чем-то другим, раз уже иностранные сотрудники начинают "важные" [вопросы постить на ruSO.Мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10159/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ага, подумывал над этим. Если сам не планируешь, то я тогда задам)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica задавай, конечно. У меня непрерывные дни посещения SO уже закончились :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329271/260198.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в общем, поговорил с CM. В целом, можно забыть про любые хотелки. У них нет времени на это (особенно после недавних увольнений).

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica На самом деле, проблема в другом. Активировать можно, но коллеги не согласны просто активировать, хотят   провести сначала А/Б тест. Вот это уже надо вносить в план, как я понял. Возможно, можно будет в список дел на следующий квартал попросить добавить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не представляю, как CM'ы планируют новый план по взаимодействию с сообществом выполнять с такими задержками =/

Comment: Наверно, он позволит задержек избежать! =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky посмотрим. Вообще, в этом плане хотелось бы, всё же, какую-то публичную тикет систему/трелло/родмеп видеть.

Answer (score 1):

Со мной связалась команда SE и по [нашим просьбам](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329271/260198) они вернули этот пункт.

> Thank you for your email! We just have activated the unanswered tab on all international sites.

Возрадуемся (:

> [image: Не отвеченные вопросы]

Comment: А для Меты чего не вернули? Снова какие-то полумеры.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хотя бы так. Уже лучше, чем ничего)

Answer (score -4):

Ну стойте. Зачем же вы берете какой-то другой сайт? Мы находимся на Stack Overflow, а это отдельная линия сайтов SE. Давайте посмотрим на другие 4 Stack Overflow — английский, португальский, испанский и японский.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

У всех других SO пункта "Неотвеченные", как видите нет. И я думаю, нам следует оставить все как есть.

Comment: То есть каких-то доводов, кроме как «на других SO такого нет» у вас нет?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ну а какие ещё нужны? Если вы хотите изменить это, то тогда вам нужно предложить это всем SO, чтобы сохранить схожесть и гармоничность всех сайтов.

Comment: нужны хотя бы такие, которые покажут минусы этого изменения. О какой-то гармоничности мультиязычных SO говорить не имеет смысла. Английская версия, например, существенно отличается от всех остальных, японская — в стадии беты, а что до испанской и португальской — надо ещё поискать таких людей, которые посещают все три сайта на регулярной основе, чтобы была важна какая-то идентичность по меню. А вот людей, посещающих одновременно «Русский язык» и «RuSO» однозначно в избытке.

Comment: @ʞɔᴉNɹǝꓥ Добавил свой [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9258/220571) как контраргумент.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Ну вот я же и сказал, что нужно это всем предложить. Так я согласен.