# Новая страница публикации вопроса доступна всем!

Tags: обсуждение, ask-question-wizard

Ура! Новая страница публикации вопроса активирована для всех участников Stack Overflow на русском!

[image]

> **В двух словах**
>
> Новая страница публикации вопроса создана, чтобы помочь задающему сориентироваться на сайте и своевременно подсказать, как улучшить итоговый вопрос. Новая страница — это объединение помощника и стандартной страницы публикации вопроса.
>
> [Подробнее про инициативу в блоге.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/)

Пожалуйста, присоединяйтесь к благодарностям команде разработчиков и невероятным переводчику [@Denis640Kb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/314403/denis640kb), а также [@Victor says reinstate Monica](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/337540/), [@edem](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199733/edem), без которых у сообщества не было бы этой страницы!

Будем рады услышать ваши отзывы в ответах к этому вопросу =)

---

О проблемах с переводом лучше репортить в [отдельной теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10161/15479).

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10083/178576

Comment: Перевод страницы требует доработки. Можно ли снять галку "проверено" с переводов текста этой страницы на transifex?

Comment: @insolor одной кнопки нет. Нужно выискивать каждое слово и отменять перевод =/

Comment: @insolor даже хуже, они никак не сгруппированы, просто сплошной список.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica а на traducir не вынесен этот текст?

Comment: @insolor вынесен, но, говорю же, там всё в общем списке. Придётся каждое слово/фразу по одному искать.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, ну хотя бы так. Позже посмотрю.

Comment: @insolor вообще, эти переводы нужно было на мете обсуждать. Не знаю, почему в этот раз решили делать в обход заведённой практики.

Comment: Крайне не нравится одно рассогласование. Кнопка тега "Код" над полем ввода - делает 4 отступа. Тогда как под окном ввода в примере используется обрамление тройным бэктиком (остальные 3 примера там - полностью соответствуют действиям соотв. кнопок). По-моему, приведение в единый вид (нажатие кнопки вставляет 3 строки - 1 и 3 состоят из 3 бэктиков, во второй слова "введите сюда код" без 4-пробельного смещения) получше будет... вот кабы ident сохранялся при нажатии *Enter* и добавлялся при копипасте - тогда да.

Answer (score 5):

Хочу сказать, что страница наконец-то перевоплотилась и выглядит красивее. Возможно, пару замечаний всё же есть и с ними кто-то не согласится, но хочется, чтобы была какая-то оф. статистика по изменению качества написания первых вопросов от новичков. Нововведение было, а принесёт ли плоды? Как помню свой первый заход - это был быстренький способ особо без разбора узнать ответ на свой вопрос, это уже в процессе познания сайта начал появляться интерес к правильному написанию.

Может, стоит попробовать ввести немного более агрессивную подсказку для новичков на сайте? Вряд ли кто-то будет читать что-то сбоку, а автоматический подсказчик, который проверит немного написание вопроса уже больше заинтересует. Например, человек написал сплошной текст без кода, нажимает "Задать ваш вопрос", тут ему сразу предлагают: "Попробуйте добавить код или оформить текст", также здесь будет вариант пропустить и отредактировать, чтобы у человека был выбор и не было такого, что обязательно нужно редактировать, тем более точно программа не может понять смысл того, что хочет сказать автор.

Также предлагаю заменить фразу "Задать ваш вопрос" на "ОТПРАВИТЬ", просто немного непонятно к чему это уточнее, либо сократить до "Задать вопрос".

Про нехватку перевода уже знаете, наверное. Если ничего не написать во время написания вопроса, то появляется `Не удалось отправить ваш вопрос. Resolve 3 issues before posting`.

В подсказках тоже не хватает, где предлагают кратко описать проблему `Include any error messages`.