# Проблемы с переводом в новой форме вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, ask-question-wizard

1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask — вот
   тут, нажав на `HTML`, видим не переведённый фрагмент текста:

   > Use HTML in combination with Markdown (What's supported? Note: We advise
   > against mixing HTML and Markdown.)
2. Должно быть "Больше о публикации качественных вопрос**ов**" и "ПосЕтите", а не "ПосИтите".

   [image]
3. Не переведено предложение в блоке “опишите проблему кратко”:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. "Будьте конкретны. Представьте, что вы задаете ваш вопрос человеку.." - две точки в конце, и лучше звучало бы "ваш вопрос другому человеку" (в оригинале "Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person")

Comment: Да там много чего непереведено ещё, начиная с "Before you post, search the site... " и "Don’t show me this again" в начальном всплывающем окне.

Comment: @Yaant "Поситите справочный центр", "Добавьте всю информацию, которая может понадобится для ответа на ваш вопрос". Интересно, кто переводы апрувил)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Наверно Nicolas.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, это общий вопрос для проблем с переводом этой страницы?

Comment: @insolor ага. Лучше всё сюда кидать, чтоб не создавать кучу постов.

Comment: Появились правки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил всё. Много чего в описаниях тегов пришлось дописать. Появится с новым обновлением движка.

Comment: Вот это же вроде она: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13384 ?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight да, но текст же там другой. Разве что, кто-то её сегодня поменял и текст просто ещё не выкатился.

Comment: Я предлагал к ней перевод пару дней назад. Возможно, его уже утвердили.В Traducir истории нет, но в Transifex должна быть.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ок, пока удалю тогда. Если со следующим обновлением не появится, будем думать)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ага, подхватилось.

Comment: Осталось "Before you post..." из моего комментария к вопросу. И еще вот - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFOE4.png (зеленым выделено несоответствие - в одном месте "Italics" и "Жирный", в другом - "bold" и "курсив").

Comment: @Yaant добавил. Завтра должно появиться.

Comment: @Yaant выкатилось)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ага, но все равно единообразия нет - теперь там "жирный" и "полужирный". Ну и "Before you post..." никуда так и не делось.

Comment: @Yaant а какой вариант у нас обычно используется?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica А это вопрос не совсем тривиальный. Вообще говоря, полужирный и жирный - это два разных начертания шрифта, отличающиеся этой самой "жирностью". В типографике "bold" - это чаще "полужирный", а "жирный" - это какой-нибудь "extra bold". Но вот в отношении сайтов - я даже и не знаю, как правильнее переводить. Я бы сказал, что можно и так и так, главное - чтобы было везде одинаково. :)

Comment: @Yaant в справке раздел называется [полужирный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#italics-bold). Будем придерживаться этого варианта)

Comment: Вижу, что "Before you post..." наконец перевелось, а вот "Don’t show me this again" в том же окне - до сих пор нет.

Comment: @Yaant как это окно вызвать? )

Comment: Ну, так-то оно само вылезает, при открытии https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask Но, видимо, если нажать на "Don't show me this again", именно это и произойдет - больше показываться не будет (я не проверял). :) Вероятно, надо очистить кукисы, ну или открыть в режиме инкогнито.

Comment: Собственно, мне там (в этом окне) еще заголовок не нравится, как-то странновато звучит, на мой вкус - "Задавая хороший вопрос". Деепричастные обороты в качестве заголовков вроде не слишком распространены в русском языке. Но, возможно, я придираюсь. :)

Comment: @Yaant вечером после работы посмотрю.