# Не переведена фраза в форме создания вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, ask-question-wizard

Не переведено `Don't show me this again`.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13447

Добавил перевод:

> Больше не показывать

Появится после обновления движка.

Comment: [Мне вот понравилось](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By59U.png)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это хорошо или плохо? )

Comment: это иначе (ц) .....

Comment: [Не прошло и месяца](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10161/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0/10201?noredirect=1#comment43117_10201) :)

Comment: @Yaant с этой работой такие вещи вообще из головы вылетают =/